# Cocoa server with user friendly automatic port forwarding or external ip lookup

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, networking, upnp

I am coding a mac app, which will be a server that serve files to each user's mobile device.

The issues with this of course are getting the actual ip/port of the server host, as it will usually be inside of a home network. If the ip/port changes, its no big as i plan to send that info to a middle-man-server first, and have my mobile app get the info from there.

I have tried upnp with https://code.google.com/p/tcmportmapper/ but even though I know my router supports upnp, the library does not work as intended.

I even tried running a TURN server on my amazon ec2 instance, but i had a very hard time figuring how what message to communicate with it to get the info i need.

I've been since last night experimenting with google's libjingle, but am having a hard time even getting the provided ios example to run.

Any advice on getting this seemingly difficult task accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

The port of your app will not change. The IP change could be handled by posting your servers IP to a web service every hour or whatever time period you want.

Server should run a URL http://your-web-service.com/serverip.php?ip=your-updated-ip and then have your serverip.php handle the rest (put it into a mySQL db or something)

When your client start it should ask your site for the IP and then connect to your server with that.

This is a pretty common way of handling this type of things.

Comment: it is not as simple as that because if there is a home router, the router will not know how to forward a request based on the ip alone. also the port should be dynamic

Comment: you could ask the user to port forward, but that is not user friendly, hence all the upnp, nat-pnp, using turn servers etc

Comment: Is Port Forwarding on your router possible?

Comment: it is possible on mine because I understand how to do that - but i want to build an app that a grandmother could use